# Excel VBA AllocConsole: Dll routine freezes after text selected in Console

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll-injection

My application has an Excel front-end. I am using VBA to call my C/C++ dll which does all the number crunching. VBA is used to communicate data between Excel and my C++ dll, and generates plots etc.

In my C++ dll, I am using `AllocConsole()` function to display a console window in which I display status updates and results.

Whenever, I select (using mouse) some displayed text in the console window; any C++ dll function called from Excel VBA (after the selection) freezes and my application becomes unresponsive.

I am not able to resolve this issue. I do not know what effect the selection in the Console window is causing to my application.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it's difficult to pinpoint the cause of this behavior, but there is a workaround, which you can use in your code.

If you have access to the source code for the DLL, instead of giving the output into the console, put the output into a **BSTR structure** (which VBA uses as a string).

Details on 'receiving' a VBA string are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263531(v=vs.60).aspx

You can modify that code to write into a string to return to VBA.

That way, you will be able to use the VBA string and put it out into your own console in the form of a VBA `UserForm`.

All UI, with this approach, will be controlled by the Excel application and the DLL will only be invoked for the numerical portion. *That should take care of the freeze*.

If you would prefer not using string, you can pass an arbitrary size byte array's pointer to C++, wherein it puts the results as a character array (VBA's `byte` is the same size as C++'s `char` data type). That way, you can

1. pass an 'empty' byte array to C++ which is "long enough for your purposes"
2. using the byte array's first element, passed by reference, C++ can populate the console output and return control back to VBA
3. VBA can then be used to trim / reformat the output and present it in the console window as a `Userform` with a large `TextBox`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am thinking going this route if I cannot sort out the console issue.